# Flutter convert json data containing \n to new lines

Tags: flutter, dart

My API sends a json with the following format:

```
{ status: false, message: 'This is an error \n\n with multi line!' }
```

I'd like to show the message and apply the new lines set in the json.

I'm using Dio package and I return the information like:

```
Response response = await Dio().post(...)
String message = response.data['message'];
```

This prints literally `This is an error \n\n with multi line!` instead of printing:

> This is an error
>
> with multi line!

[image]

If I type manually `String message = 'This is an error \n\n with multi line!'` it works great.

It seems to me that I have to use `replaceAll` function, but I don't know what to replace.

Comment: Try this replaceAll('\\n', '\n');

Comment: @Kohls set as an answer so I can accept it, because it works!

Comment: done made it bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
replaceAll('\\n', '\n');
```